# How do I make components like a grid display immediately using Rally's SDK 2?

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I create a rallygrid and put it in one of the containers that's listed as an item for the app.  Then, the app is cycling through a for loop that can take up to three minutes to create and add other grids to the page.

1. The app waits until all of the grids are created and added to the page before displaying any of them.  How can I get the first one to show up once it's added to the component?
2. Is there a rule-of-thumb for fastest way to add a whole bunch of things? I'm adding 100+ grids for some minor summary data. Each one is given a little array, but I make a store and then a grid.
3. While it's cycling through the 100+ little grids, I can't do anything to stop it from finishing its execution.  Since the whole thing is kicked off by a change in an attributebox, changing the drop-down by the user doesn't do anything for some time.  And I can't even close the Chrome tab while it's building.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspending Ext layouts during rendering may help speed things up:

```
Ext.suspendLayouts();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    addGrids...
}
Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```

If suspending layouts is still too slow, try adding the grids asynchronously. This won't actually speed up the rendering, but it may help the UI feel more responsive. Combining the suspendLayouts trick with asynchronous rendering will not work, you'll have to choose one or the other:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var addGrid = function() {
        addGrid...
    }

    Ext.Function.defer(addGrid, i * 200);
}
```

100 grids is a lot of dom. It will likely be slow no matter what method you are using. Be careful if you are targeting IE, I suspect 100 grids on a single page in IE will be unusable.